# My App Crashes when calling my Animation?

Tags: android, animation

I have an AnimationDrawable object, when I call the wavingAndroid method, the game crashes. Any help? 
Here's my MainActivity.java

```
    private void wavingAndroid(){
ImageView animateAndroid = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dancingAndroidLogo);
animateAndroid.setImageResource(R.drawable.movingandroid);
AnimationDrawable androidAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) animateAndroid.getDrawable();
androidAnimation.start();
    }
```

and I'm trying to call it here:

```
    public void onClick(View v){
    wavingAndroid();
    }
```

Here's my xml file:

```
    <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true" >

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo01"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo02"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo03"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo04"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo05"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo06"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo07"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo08"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo09"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo10"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo11"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo12"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo13"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo14"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo15"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo16"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo17"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo18"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo19"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo20"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo21"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo22"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo23"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo24"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo25"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo27"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo28"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo29"
    android:duration="41"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo30"
    android:duration="41"/>

<!-- Reset to original -->
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/dancinglogo01"
    android:duration="10"/>

    </animation-list>
```

Here's my logcat:

```
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392): java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at         com.thatnerdstuff.build_a_rig.MainActivity.wavingAndroid(MainActivity.java:149)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at com.thatnerdstuff.build_a_rig.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:145)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at com.thatnerdstuff.build_a_rig.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4203)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17189)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
    08-17 09:59:22.487: E/AndroidRuntime(22392):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help on the matter would be fantastic, as I've looked at many other forums, and such to try and find the fix, and I don't know where it's coming from. I've tried cleaning the project and nothing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is at row 149? com.thatnerdstuff.build_a_rig.MainActivity.wavingAndroid(MainActivity.java:149)

Comment: androidAnimation.start(); @matheszabi

Comment: androidAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) animateAndroid.getDrawable(); returns null thats the problem, which needs to solve it

Comment: some thing null inside `wavingAndroid` debug it!

Comment: I ran the app in debug and it's saying my variable animateAndroid = null, but I set it equal to (AnimationDrawable)animateAndroid.getDrawable();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading images to AnimationDrawable in code, like this:

```
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation= new AnimationDrawable();
frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dancinglogo01), 41);
frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dancinglogo02), 41);
```

Add all the frames like this in your `wavingAndroid()` method, then load it to imageView like this

```
animateAndroid = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dancingAndroidLogo);
animaateAndroid.setBackgroundDrawable(frameAnimation);
```

Now in your `onClick()` method start the animation using:

```
frameAnimation.start();
```